# How to intercept URL int iPhone's Default web browser?

Tags: iphone, browser

Is there any private API by which I can intercept url which user tries to open from default iPhone browser?

Is there any web kit framework in iPhone?

Comment: @Jonathan: globally... I want whenever any app/standard browser tries to open URL, my app should intercept it.

Comment: Any URL at all? Or just a custom URL scheme like `myapp://`?

Comment: You can't, thank god, and you never will be able to. That would be a huge security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following webview delegate.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString * URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

return YES; //return NO; to stop loading

}
```

Comment: Which protocol I should implement to use this delegate? Is this delegate be called by my app when any other app/default browser tries to open URL?